# What is the issue with the following excel code?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been asked to work out what the problem is with this piece of excel code, can anyone help? Thanks.

```
=IF(EO3=TRUE,"Bed",IF(EP3=TRUE,"Chair,IF(EQ3=TRUE,"Sofa",IF(ER3=TRUE,"Table"))))
```

Comment: you do not need the `=TRUE` not your problem but you can make it shorter: `=IF(EO3,"Bed",IF(EP3,"Chair",IF(EQ3,"Sofa",IF(ER3,"Table"))))`  The problem is what @daniel stated.  You also do not tell it what to do if all 4 are false.  currently it will return `FALSE` if all four are false.

Comment: You could also do:`=INDEX({"Bed","Chair","Sofa","Table"},MATCH(TRUE,EO3:ER3,0))`

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Really appreciate the additional info.

Answer (score 3):

> "Chair

Missing the closing double quotation on the word Chair :)

Comment: Thanks so much, Daniel. Much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem - I'm happy I was able to help :)